# How to bring a bridge interface down when physical interface gets unplugged?

Tags: networking, usb, lxc, network-bridge

I have configured a bridge for LXC in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
# Internet
iface enx0050b6130ce2 inet manual

# Bridge for LXC
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports enx0050b6130ce2
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```

The physical interface is a USB network adapter. The is the reason why it has this funky interface name. When I unplug the USB adapter the bridge is broken.

How can I bring `br0` down, when `enx0050b6130ce2` gets unplugged? And how can I bring `br0` up, when `enx0050b6130ce2` gets plugged in?

I know I can use `auto` but this does not help, because I need to configure a different interface than those plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I think I got it myself.

```
# Internet
allow-hotplug enx0050b6130ce2
iface enx0050b6130ce2 inet manual
    pre-up ifup br0
    down ifdown br0

# Bridge für LXC
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports enx0050b6130ce2
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
```